# Why multi-cell array formula is not allowed in an excel table?

Tags: excel, array-formulas

Multi-cell array formulas allows you to apply a formula to whole a column in excel. 
e.g.:

```
{=B10:B20+C10:C20}
```

Why multi-cell array formula is not allowed in an excel table? In a table you can only use individual formulas, like `=B10+C10`, `=B11+C11`, ... But then you can use a different formula in row. Array formula would prevent this.

Comment: The real question is why does it matter? What is the problem here?

Comment: While using `{=B10:B20+C10:C20}` applied as multi-cell-array-formula in rows 10:20 you cannot insert new rows between row 10 and row 20. So the table could not grow on if such formulas where allowed.

Comment: at row insert excel should modify the formula to {=B10:B21+C10:C21}; An array formula is better than individual formulas because it express that a whole column contains the same formula. Moreover, it does not allow to change accidently just one element.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are talking about Excel Table created by Ctrl + L. For such kind of tables, you can choose the whole column to set a formula, Excel will regard that as the "column formula" of your column. Then every new row will automatically apply it, and Excel will even alert you after manually modifying the formula of a cell of this column to something else. Isn't it enough?

Comment: @COY   You are right, excel will auto copy formulas in a table column. I use this now. But the main idea of array formulas is that you can not  overwrite an individual formula accidentally. Array formula should be quicker and smaller in file size. It should work in excel tables.

Comment: I see...then as a workaround, I think you may also try to make use of the Locking feature. By default, all cells are locked and the worksheet Protection is OFF. To lock particular columns, choose the other columns you need to edit, in properties, unlock them, turn ON the worksheet Protection.